# Number of Impressions on Admob for Revenue

Tags: android, revenue

Just curious for a rough estimate; how many impressions would it take to make 300 dollars, a day, in ad revenue?

Comment: Wow, 300 dollars a DAY? A whole TON of impressions, I'd guess! I'm anxious to know the answer though.

Comment: I just read a report about the shotgun app on the iphone making 900 a day... so I mean it is realistic.

Comment: define "realistic".

Comment: Realistic to make 300 dollars a day... meaning that if a simple useless app such as shotgun can rake in 900 a day in revenue, then it does not seem like a stretch that a simple but more engaging game can make a third of that a day.

Comment: It's certainly possible. My first facebook app peaked at around $200 a day, and that was with 80k active users. Only lasted for about 2 months though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about admob, not game development.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not possible to determine an accurate estimate, because the rate of each click-through or impression changes for each ad that is displayed.

However, if we take some made up stats from http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Definitions, it gives that you could theoretically have a estimated cost-per-1000-impression (eCPM) of $1.11. Based on that, it means you would need over 270,000 **unique** impressions a day to make $300. If your eCPM was only half of that, you would have to double the numbers.

If we look at the cost-per-click model, and you assume the average cost-per-click is $0.30 (again, a made up figure obtained from the link above), then it will take 1000 **unique** clicks a day to make $300/day.

Remember, the above stats are completely made up. Each person will have a different experience and the only true way to find out is to implement it in your app and record your own stats.

Comment: Hey thanks for that link!  Tons of help.  Just looking to see around about number of daily users I need to get to make a free app profitable.

Answer (score 14):

I can give some stat from AdMod for a long running game to give you some ideas.

- Last 7 days: eCPM $0.21, impressions 2.7M, fill rate 99%
- Last 90 days: eCPM $0.28, impressions 31.4M, fill rate 99%
- Last 365 days: eCPM $0.32, impressions 133M, fill rate 92%

This is with AdWords enabled for when there are no graphical ads to show.

You'll also notice that there is quite a seasonal effect. eCPM varies quite a bit, so take the 32c as a baseline to figure out your $300/day. It would take ~1M impressions a day.

Also note that it depends on the frequency and placement of your ads. Too many of them will annoy the user, etc.

Comment: This is what this question really needed - real world data.

Comment: Thanks for the hard data! I am curious what the figures are as of 2020!

Answer (score 7):

You may have 100,000 impressions and may be 0 revenue.
It all depends on number of clicks you have which is measured by eCPM. 
If you had more clicks in the initial period of launch but later it decreases, you will see decrease in eCPM and your revenue if eCPM * Impressions/1000.

So, if you are fortunate and your App Users likes the ads that pops up and click on them, you make money else you may make little or no money if the users don't click.

My experience:
In last 1 week, the impressions on my app went up by 5000 and no change in revenue because no one clicked on the ads appearing on my App.

Good luck...